# How to create KSQLdb stream using EXTRACTJSONFIELD(message, '$.payload.version')

Tags: ksqldb

How do I create a a KSQLdb stream of value_type JSON using EXTRACTJSONFIELD? Would this be done using a select statement? I am not clear how field names could be defined for the stream during creation of the stream using EXTRACTJSONFIELD operator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `AS` to alias the field name. Here's an example.

Dummy source data:

```
 ksql> PRINT 'source_data' FROM BEGINNING;
 Format:JSON
 {"ROWTIME":1545239521600,"ROWKEY":"null","Header":{"RecType":"RecA"},"RAFld1":{"someFld":"some data","someOtherField":1.001},"RAFld2":{"aFld":"data","anotherFld":98.6}}
 {"ROWTIME":1545239526600,"ROWKEY":"null","Header":{"RecType":"RecB"},"RBFld1":{"randomFld":"random data","randomOtherField":1.001}}
```

Declare the source stream

```
 CREATE STREAM my_stream (Header VARCHAR, 
                          RAFld1 VARCHAR, 
                          RAFld2 VARCHAR, 
                          RBFld1 VARCHAR) 
 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='source_data', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Create the derived stream

```
 CREATE STREAM recA_data WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS 
 SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(RAFld1,'$.someOtherField') AS someOtherField, 
         EXTRACTJSONFIELD(RAFld1,'$.someFld')        AS someFld, 
         EXTRACTJSONFIELD(RAFld2,'$.aFld')           AS aFld, 
         EXTRACTJSONFIELD(RAFld2,'$.anotherFld')     AS anotherFld 
         FROM my_stream \
 WHERE EXTRACTJSONFIELD(Header,'$.RecType') = 'RecA';
```

([Source](https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/heterogeneous-json-structures/))

Comment: Thats awsome! Thanks

Comment: When might this be preferred to using a STRUCT?

Comment: Also I notice that the format of recA_data is AVRO is that required or preferable?

Comment: Since you're applying a schema then a format that supports it (Avro / Protobuf / JSON Schema) makes sense.